# Finding partial fractions including complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, partial-fractions

I got a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2503220/can-someone-explain-the-steps-of-this-partial-fraction-decomposition/2503239#2503239) when finding the partial fraction decomposition.

[image]

Here $i$ is imaginary number.

I set up the equation like this and I am confused here:
$$
\frac{e^{ikx}}{(x-2i)(x+2i)}=\frac{Ai+B}{(x+2i)}+\frac{Ci+D}{(x-2i)}
$$

$$
e^{ikx}=(Ai+B)(x-2i)+(Ci+D)(x+2i)
$$

When $x = 2i$
$$
e^{-2k}=(Ci+D)(4i)
$$

When $x = -2i$
$$
e^{2k}=(Ai+B)(-4i)
$$

Comment: You can immediately see that $D=B=0$ because both LHS are real

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the image example at the top, the partial fraction decomposition still includes the $e^{ikx}$ term. When you're trying to set up your own partial fractions, you're forgetting to include the $e^{ikx}$ on RHS. That's what's getting you into trouble here.

To calculate the right partial fraction decomposition, you should instead start out like
$$\frac{e^{ikx}}{(x-2i)(x+2i)}=\frac{(Ai+B) e^{ikx}}{(x+2i)}+\frac{(Ci+D)e^{ikx}}{(x-2i)}$$
Or better yet, just remove the $e^{ikx}$ from both sides like
$$\frac{1}{(x-2i)(x+2i)}=\frac{Ai+B}{(x+2i)}+\frac{Ci+D}{(x-2i)}$$
(but if you go this route remember to multiply all your terms by $e^{ikx}$ at the end!)